# PHP copy() creates an empty image file

Tags: php, image, copy

I have one image in a directory on my server, and want to copy it to another directory.

So I'm using

```
$post_picture = 'http://mysite.com/image.jpg';

copy($post_picture, 
         'images/pictures/post/thumb/' . 
         $info['filename'] . 
         '_thumb.' . 
         $info['extension']);
```

The issue is that in fact a file is created in my `thumb` directory, but that image is empty (0 x 0 pixels). I get no errors.

Any idea what is happening?

Permissions on all dirs are 755, both original and copy image have 644. The original show normally on a browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it an empty file, or is it a 0x0 pixel image?

Comment: Why are you using image URL instead of its normal path? Isn't that image on your server? Is PHP able to fetch URLs (see *allow_url_fopen* option)?

Comment: allow_url_fopen is on (both local and master)

Comment: @kavisiegel the image is 41KB but 0x0

Comment: lorenzo-s the image is on my server but copy allows URL

Comment: @torr In that case, please post the contents of the file

Comment: @lorenzo kavisiegel, solved this see below - thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have any form of hot-link protection that could alter what php receives?
Is allow_url_fopen allowed?

Comment: looks like `copy()` was failing because of a redirect in my .htaccess - once I commented that out the file shows normally - thanks for pointing this out -- I am now using full system path instead of URL and it works even with the redirect

Answer (score 1):

The `$post_picture` variable should *probably* have the file system path to the file, rather than the URL to the file.

Comment: `copy()` supports URLs. We do not know if the image is fetched from the same server or not. See my questions in the question comments.

Comment: You're right so it does. Missed it when I quickly check the php manual page.

Answer (score 0):

Is allow_url_fopen set to true in your php.ini?

Sometimes that can produce this result if remote connections are being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

$post_picture should be a local path i believe

```
copy( '/path/image.jpg', ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this one...

```
<?php
$source = 'f-1/2.jpg';
$destination = 'f-2/2.jpg';

$data = file_get_contents($source);

$handle = fopen($destination, "w");
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);
?>
```